# I would Like to trap when the UIEditor has closed in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to trap when my custom UIEditor has closed, does anyone have a sugestion.

Brad

EDIT:

a recent comment was to fire an event and for interested parties to intercept it. I am not entirely sure how accomplish this. Below is the declaration for my property and the declaration for the editor. But how would I hook the editor’s event after firing?

WINFORM's

```
    private string _filename;
    [Browsable(true), Category("Source name"),
    Description("Image Source name"),
     Editor(typeof(FileOpenEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]

    public string ImageFileName
    {
        get { return _filename; }
        set { _filename = value;}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every form in C# has a Closing event that you can wire-up to. Where does your editor/form get created? That's where you'll want to wire-up to the closing event. If you need to propagate that to other parties, then you'll have to chain it.

Comment: I am okay with that concept - but how do I wire up to the uieditor when it is part of the attributes ( term?) of a property?

Comment: It has to get created somewhere. Follow the code. Just because it is declared on a property via an attribute, that doesn't mean anything. Somewhere the form actually has to get created. Do you control that, or is that part of some 3rd party framework?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your UI editor ought to fire an event when it's closing, and any interested parties should subscribe to the event.